# How do I put a copyrighted background in a PowerPoint presentation?

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, presentations, copy-protection

- I want all the slides to have the same background
- Also, the slides should be editable, but the background should be neither editable nor copyable

**Is that possible in Microsoft PowerPoint? If not, does any other presentation software for Windows allow this?**

Comment: The problem with this is that, well what happens if someone deletes all the overlaying content and just takes a screenshot?

Answer (score 4):

If you are going to be distributing this presentation, there is *no* way that you can entirely lock somebody out of copying the background. If somebody is determined to get that image, they will. They can make a screenshot, they can extract the contents of the .pptx and find the image file, etc. If you can't risk having the image "escape", then just don't use it, because if somebody is determined, they will get it.

If you were to use flash to make the presentation, you could potentially make it impossible for a user to extract the image, but they could still take a screenshot. The work required to make your own editable presentation software in flash would be ridiculous though.

Basically, your best option is to either use the master slide so that it's harder for users to edit it and to get the consistency, or else don't use that image.